# Is there a reason my tenant is in red text in QnA maker?

Tags: azure-qna-maker

I'm in qnamaker trying to find my knowledge base and I was using a free azure account.  That has expired, however, I want to get my knowledge base.  The tenant is red when i try and select it.  All tenants does not pull up a knowledge base either.

Do KB's expire?  Is it tied to my subscription?  (I re-enabled it today to see if that's it).

I really just need to grab it and move the qna over to a new sub.  [enter image description here][1]

Comment: It should be tied to your subscription. KB don't expire. If you re-enabled it, perhaps it just takes a bit of time for it to become available? Also make sure all the resources along with the cognitive resource (Search for example) appear as working in the azure portal as well. If all that checks out, open a help request in azure. FYI, your image/screenshot didn't show.

Comment: ok, thank you.  It actually did appear now.  Took a lot of time for that to repopulate after i re-activated.  like 2 days.  Thank you for the reply.